# Umlaut in a table name

Tags: php, sql-server, php-5.6

I have a problem in PHP 5.6.30
The  name of the table in SQL Server contains Ö. How can I access the table? Ot worked without any problems in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Show your code that works in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Try with [_backticks_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) around the table name: `SELECT * FROM \`aüböcä\``.